# Semaphore to control access over the shared resource

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrency, semaphore

I have a use case where I am implementing access to ATM Machine for users, using `Semaphore` class from `java.util.concurrent` package as lock i.e. to lock the access to the resource.

Any thread that wants to access the *locked resource* calls the `acquire()` method before accessing the resource, to acquire the lock and releases the lock by calling the `release()` method, after the completion of the task.

**Implementation Code :**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class ATMMachine {
    
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Semaphore machines = new Semaphore(1,true);
        new Person(machines, "A");
        new Person(machines, "B");
        new Person(machines, "C");
    }
}

class Person extends Thread {
    
    private Semaphore machines;
    
    public Person(Semaphore machines, String name) {
        this.machines = machines;
        this.setName(name);
        this.start();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(getName()+ " is waiting to access the ATM machine");
            machines.acquire();
            System.out.println(getName()+ " is accessing the ATM machine");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(getName()+ " is done using the ATM machine");
            machines.release();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            System.err.println(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
A is waiting to access the ATM machine
C is waiting to access the ATM machine
B is waiting to access the ATM machine
A is accessing the ATM machine
A is done using the ATM machine
C is accessing the ATM machine
C is done using the ATM machine
B is accessing the ATM machine
B is done using the ATM machine
```

**Issue** : Every time I run the program, output changes. But, I want to make sure that access to the machines is to be given to the users in order : **A → then B → lastly C**

**Note** : I have set `fair` parameter as `true` in the constructor, which should guarantee FIFO to the threads in the order they are requested. But it doesn't seem to work.

Request you to help me out with any suggestions/references to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem where you need to maintain the strict order of threads requesting the access to shared resource can not be solved by semaphore / mutex.
You need to implement a locking mechanism which will support the FIFO order for granting the access to the shared resource. Lets call this locking mechanism FIFO Mutex. You can implement this FIFO mutex using [Ticket Locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock).

I've implemented pseudo code for the FIFO mutex. It may help you. Checkout here:
https://codeistry.wordpress.com/2018/03/21/fifo-mutex/

Pseudo code for FIFO Mutex class:

```
class FifoMutex
{
public:
 
    FifoMutex();
    ~FifoMutex();
    void
    lock();
    void
    unlock();
 
private:
 
    UINT32 m_nowServing;
    UINT32 m_nextAvailable;
    ConditionMutex *m_condMutex;
};
 
FifoMutex::FifoMutex()
{
    m_nowServing = 0;
    m_nextAvailable = 0;
    m_condMutex = new ConditionMutex();
}
void
FifoMutex::lock()
{
    UINT32 myTicket;
 
    // Get your ticket and increment the m_nextAvailable.
    m_condMutex->lock();
        myTicket = m_nextAvailable;
        m_nextAvailable++;
    m_condMutex->unlock();
 
    // Wait till your ticket is getting served.
    m_condMutex->lock();
        while (m_nowServing != myTicket) {
            m_condMutex->wait();
        }
    m_condMutex->unlock();
}
 
void
FifoMutex::unlock()
{
    // Increment the m_nowServing and wakeup all blocked threads.
    m_condMutex->lock();
        m_nowServing++;
        // Pl note we are broadcasting the wakeup call.
        // We must broadcast since we don't know 
        // which thread should acquire the lock next.
        // All the waiting threads will be unblocked, 
        // only one of them will pass condition: "m_nowServing == myTicket"
        m_condMutex->broadcast();
    m_condMutex->unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not controlling the order in which each thread calls `.acquire` — you are simply launching 3 threads and whichever calls the "fair" `.acquire` first will win. Sometimes it will be A, sometimes B, sometimes C.

Also note that the "FIFO guarantee" may not be as strong as you're thinking — it's not really about who the order of the calls to `.acquire` per se, but to an ordering point within that function.

So if you *need* A, then B, then C, a Semaphore is not the correct solution. If you need sequential access to the resource, with a specific sequence, then why not simplify everything and use a single thread for everything?

Comment: Thank you! This is insightful. Actually, I was reading about semaphores and thought of implementing the use case, using it. But as you said a single thread would serve the purpose and would be more apt.

Comment: you can do with using semaphore but without threads.